# What is the keyword for a tuple?

Tags: python, tuples

I'm trying to find the keyword for a `tuple` like the keyword "list"

this is my example:

input:

```py
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
if type(list1) == list:
    print("this is a list")
```

output:

```py
this is a list
```

I would like to know what the keyword is for a tuple instead of list.

Comment: It's simply tuple.

Comment: Did you try `tuple`?

Comment: `print(type((1,1)))`

Comment: `print(type((1,1)))`

Comment: Note, these aren't keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type of tuple in Python is simply `tuple`

Answer (score 5):

You can just use `tuple`. You may also want to use `isinstance`:

```py
tuple1 = (1, 2, 3)
if isinstance(tuple1, tuple):
    print("this is a tuple")
```

Answer (score 0):

`tuple` itself a type keyword. simply just check it

```
t = (1, 2, 3)
if type(t) == tuple:
    print("this is a tuple")
# this is a tuple
```